# Microsoft word 2013 is cutting off top of text in tables

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

The following is happening to me:

[image]

I can't for the life of me figure out why

Comment: It might be specific to the font or formatting you are using. Is it happening with the default standard fonts? (It would be easier to tell if you share a sample Doc.)

Comment: What are the line spacing and space between paragraph set to?

Answer (score 1):

I had to set my 'line spacing' on right hand side to "single" as it was set to "exactly 5.5".
So i would try this :)
[image: formatting dialogue]